# Manter formatação de um palavra substituida em documento usando python-docx

Tags: python, microsoft-word

Estou criando uma tela interativa, para preenchimento de um termo de responsabilidade, afim de agilizar o processo de edição via word. Já consegui criar a tela onde é feito a entrada de dados e o codigo para ser gerado o documento novo a partir de um que é a base. Porém ao digitar os dados ele não fica com a formatação original. Gostaria de manter a formatação.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from docx import Document
from datetime import datetime

dia = str(datetime.now().day)
mes = str(datetime.now().month)
ano = str(datetime.now().year)


documento = Document("termo_de_resp.docx")

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Nome do Colaborador:"), sg.InputText(key="vNome")],
    [sg.Text("Data de Admissão(Colocar no formato DD/MM/AAAA)):"), sg.InputText(key="vAdmissao")],
    [sg.Text("C.P.F.:"), sg.InputText(key="vCPF")],
    [sg.Text("Cargo:"), sg.InputText(key="vCargo")],
    [sg.Text("Setor:"), sg.InputText(key="vSetor")],
    [sg.Text("Empresa de cadastro:"), (sg.Combo(['Empresa 1', 'Empresa 2', 'Empresa 3'], key='vEmpresa'))],
    #[sg.Text("Empresa de cadastro:"), sg.InputText()],
    #[sg.Text("Endereço do CNPJ:"), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("Equipamento:"), sg.InputText(key="vEquip")],
    [sg.Text("Valor:"), sg.InputText(key="vValor")],
    [sg.Text("Valor por extenso:"), sg.InputText(key="vExtens")],
    [sg.Text("Patrimônio:"), sg.InputText(key="vPat")],
    [sg.Button("Gerar termo")]
]

janela = sg.Window("Gerador de Termos de Responsabilidade", layout)

while True:

    evento, valores = janela.read()
    if evento == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if evento == "Gerar termo":
        nm = valores["vNome"] #armazenar nome
        admissao = valores["vAdmissao"] #armazenar data de admissão
        cpf = valores["vCPF"] #armazenar CPF
        cargo = valores["vCargo"]
        setor = valores["vSetor"] #armazenar setor
        empresa = valores["vEmpresa"] #armazenar empresa

        if empresa == 'Empresa 1':
            cnpj = "CNPJ Empresa 1"
            end_cnpj = "Endereço empresa 1"
        elif empresa == 'Empresa 2':
            cnpj = "Cnpj empresa 2"
            end_cnpj = "Endereço empresa 2" 
        elif empresa == 'Empresa 3':
            cnpj = "CNPJ Empresa 3"
            end_cnpj = "Endereço empresa 3"
        else:
            cnpj = "Não informado"
            end_cnpj = "Não informado"

        equip = valores["vEquip"]  #armazenar tipo de equipamento
        val_equip = valores["vValor"] #armazenar valor do equipamento
        val_ext = valores["vExtens"] #armazenar valor por extenso
        pat = valores["vPat"]
        print(f"{nm}")
        print(f"{cpf}")
        print(f"{setor}")
        print(f"{empresa}")
        print(f"{equip}")
        print(f"{val_equip}")
        print(f"{val_ext}")
        print(f"{pat}")

        referencias = {
            "nomedocolaborador" : nm,
            "datadeadmissao" : admissao,
            "cpfcolaborador" : cpf,
            "cargocolaborador" : cargo,
            "setorcolaborador" : setor,
            "empresacolaborador" : empresa,
            "cnpjempresa" : cnpj,
            "enderecoempresa" : end_cnpj,
            "equipamentocolaborador" : equip,
            "valorequipamento" : val_equip,
            "valorporextenso" : val_ext,
            "patrimonioequipamento" : pat,
        }

        for paragrafo in documento.paragraphs:
            for codigo in referencias:
                valor = referencias[codigo]
                paragrafo.text = paragrafo.text.replace(codigo, valor)
                


        documento.save(f"Termo de Responsabilidade {equip} - {nm} {dia}-{mes}-{ano}.docx")






janela.close()
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.